# Bug in Django queryset with count?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-1.5

As you can guess I am having a really weird issue.
I have a queryset who returns nothing(even when it should) but still returns a value of one when using count() on it.

Here are the models:

```
import hashlib
import random
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models


class EmailChangeLogManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(EmailChangeLogManager, self).get_query_set().filter(state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING)

    def create_new_request(self, user):
        request = self.model(user=user)
        request.save()
        return request


class EmailChangeLog(models.Model):
    """
    logs the users requests to change their email
    """
    PENDING = 0
    CHANGED = 1

    objects = EmailChangeLogManager()

    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())
    token = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)  # primary key so it blows up in case of collision
    state = models.SmallIntegerField()
    new_email = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __init__(self, user, * args, **kwargs):
        super(EmailChangeLog, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
        username = user.username
        if isinstance(username, unicode):
            username = username.encode('utf-8')
        self.token = hashlib.sha1(salt+username).hexdigest()
        self.user = user
        self.state = EmailChangeLog.PENDING
```

And here is the part of the view who fails with IndexError:

```
if EmailChangeLog.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING).count() > 0:
    context['new_email'] = EmailChangeLog.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING)[0].new_email
```

I ran the following lines after after putting a break point:

```
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING).count()
Out[1]: 1
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING)
Out[2]: []
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.all().count()
Out[3]: 2
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING).count()
Out[4]: 1
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING)
Out[5]: []
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.all().count()
Out[6]: 2
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.all()
Out[7]: []
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
Out[8]: []
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.filter(state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING)
Out[9]: []
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.filter()
Out[10]: []
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.all()
Out[11]: []
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.all().count()
Out[1]: 2
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.all()
Out[3]: []
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.all()
Out[5]: []
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.all().count()
Out[6]: 2
>>> EmailChangeLog.objects.all().count()
Out[7]: 2
>>> az = EmailChangeLog.objects.all()
>>> az
Out[9]: []
>>> az.count()
Out[10]: 2
```

Is this a bug in django ? If not what is going on ?

PS: I am using django 1.5.1

EDIT: the same happens using manage shell_plus

Comment: It is not a bug. The evaluation of the queryset objects is lazy - That means it does not fetch the queryset results unless it is consumed. For example: Even though `EmailChangeLog.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING)` returns `[]` - If you do `EmailChangeLog.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING)[:1]` - It would return a queryset as it is evaluated at that point of time.

Comment: @karthikr: accessing it with index 0 raises a IndexError exception, also printing the query should consume it ? btw : [:0] does the same

Comment: I meant `[:1]` or `[0]`

Comment: it fails with IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @maazza: What do you get when yo do something like `objects.all()[0]`

Comment: @games Brainiac , I still have the same IndexError exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I figured out where my problem was, it was in the **init** function, I got rid of it and used my manager's code instead, but I still think something is wrong with the queryset on django's side.

```
class EmailChangeLogManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(EmailChangeLogManager, self).get_query_set().filter(state=EmailChangeLog.PENDING)

    def create_new_request(self, user):
        request = self.model()
        salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
        username = user.username
        if isinstance(username, unicode):
            username = username.encode('utf-8')
        request.token = hashlib.sha1(salt+username).hexdigest()
        request.user = user
        request.save()
        return request
```

EDIT:

> There seems to be two things going on:
>
> 1) You have overriden the model's init in a way that is incompatible to what Django 
>   expects. You can't add user arg to it, you might be able to use user kwarg instead. 
>   Basically, the signature must be *args, **kwargs, or Django will not be able to load 
>   your models back from DB.
>
> 2) There is a bug in Python (IIRC) that causes errors inside list(qs) to swallow 
>   the error and return empty list. This is fixed in 1.6.

It seems this bug is fixed in 1.6.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20795#comment:4